# Is it possible to have dynamic RewriteBase on .htacess?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I made a CodeIgniter based website.
I write a .htaccess as suggested in http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite

Since I put my web directory in public_html/ci_try, It is necessary to change

```
RewriteBase /
```

into

```
RewriteBase /ci_try
```

But, everytime I change the location, I should edit htacess.
Is there a way to make such a "dynamic rewrite-base" or other way so that I don't need to repeat my self editing htaccess?

UPDATE :
For now I use php to generate htaccess. But I want to know if there is a better solution out there to be accepted

Comment: How would that hypothetical dynamic rewrite base know that you've moved your content?

Comment: How often would you be moving this to make it useful anyway?

Comment: @lanzz : something like "current_url"

Comment: @Hailwood : not so often. But my site is an installable CMS. So I guess everytime it is installed, a new htaccess should be created.

Comment: having your cms create the .htaccess file is a bad idea, that leaves it writable by other scripts too. As for the installable cms, if you have at the end of the install "please set the rewrite base in .htaccess to..." Then that should suffice, check out how favourite.com do it.

Comment: @Hailwood: that's a great advice. I will consider the write permission. Also I will check favourite.com. Thanks for your great comment

Comment: Oops that was cibonfire.com. Writing comments on my phone and autocorrect got me!

Comment: I see. that's why I found nothing on favourite.com. BTW it would be great to have your advice for my CMS. Please visit my github repo : https://github.com/goFrendiAsgard/No-CMS