# How would you decouple a PHP app from needing to be run in document root?

Tags: php, relative-path, absolute-path

Currently our PHP app requires to be set up in the web server's document root (usually by configuring Apache's virtual hosts).

The main reason for that dependency is that our URL-generation logic assumes that all URLs can be accessed through the absolute path `/`. That makes for easy linking to resources such as images, and pages.

The user may be visiting the app from different sub-folders, so we cannot assume a simple relative path to work.

How would we decouple the app from needing to run in the document root of the web server? Would you suggest parsing `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in that URL controller to try to decide how far down in the filesystem the file is being accessed? Right now, I don't see a sure-fire way of doing that parsing. Also a complication here is that we use Apache's ReRewrite so URLs don't necessarily match the file system.

Comment: I found that PHP is only part of the problem when you run a site in a folder; CSS -> image references are horrible with relative links.

Comment: Ah, that's true, with the path being relative to the URL that called the CSS file. That has always been an annoyance :)

Comment: @Jack though indeed using relative links in css is less intuitive it certainly is possible. Usually the reason why issues arise is because of an unclear structure if files used, especially css files. Cleanup the project layout and things get a lot easier.

Comment: Indeed anchoring a web app to its installation path is not a trivial thing. Pure parsing of requests will not provide suffucient information. This is what is usually done: you define a 'base path' inside the apps configuration. That configuration is either explicitly edited whilst installing the app (reliable and flexible, but annoying), or it is generated by the app itself by means of a 'first run' wizzard. I found the latter to be wildely accepted although it is not really elegant from a technical point of view.

Comment: Do you have a single index.php that serves all the pages?

Comment: @arkascha with a new project that's all fine; the fun starts when you decide to reorganize an existing project :)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is not a single index.php file routing all requests. I had implemented it the old-school way of using `.htaccess` to route pretty URLs, and some other scripts are referenced directly by their URL.

Comment: @arkascha At first thought, that should work. We already have a config file, and indeed is has the "what is the URL that the app is located at" already set. I'm trying to think whether our `.htaccess` rules in the root would complicate matters where there are internal redirects happening.

Comment: @jack yep, that's why I wrote 'cleanup'...

Comment: Indeed `.htaccess` style files will have to be written by the wizzard as well. Or you have to take a more modular approach like rewriting maps, but in my experience that is even more complicated to setup.

Comment: So when you're taking about a wizzard, it would be a Bash script, for example, that would generate a customized `.htaccess` file and write it to disk?

Comment: Edit: a script might be a real security risk I'm thinking, so it might be more of an installation guide for whoever is setting up the app to create their own `.htaccess` file. However, that still quite a messy solution IMO. Would this following suggestion be the best option? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927083/is-it-possible-to-have-dynamic-rewritebase-on-htacess#comment14282349_10927083

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Refactor the existing program to route all requests through a single script (suggested above, but it's not practical for our project)
2. Use [smudge and clean attribute filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198193/how-to-handle-versioning-of-htaccess-file), requiring some relativley advanced git.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use a Simple and Stupid method for this purpose like:

If users can access indeterministically from different entry points of the application, the entry points should know "where they are" relatively to the application root.

First I should know the relative position of my current script w.r. application root so I statically write into the script i.e;
For a script that should be at

```
...approotdirname/appsubdir1name/appsubdir2name/here.php
```

.

```
$relPath = 'approotdirname/appsubdir1name/appsubdir2name';
```

- Note that if your script is **at** the application root, the $curPath calculated below will be directly your application position on the server.

Second I should learn the current script file path from Php with a uniform format:

```
$curPath = str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__));
```

(str_replace is for replacing \ with / in case they exist.)
 In fact a copy of the $relPath (if figured correctly) should exist at the end of the $curPath.

Then I will find the position of $relPath in the $curPath:

```
$p = stripos($curPath, $relPath, 0);
if(($p === false)||($p < 0)){echo "Relative path: $relPath is invalid."; exit(0);}
```

Now when we subtract $relPath from $curPath we get where on earth is our application root positioned on the server with a little checking.

```
$rootPath = ($p > 0)? substr($curPath, 0, $p-1): '/';
```

I hope this helps.

Please note that restricting user access through a single point like an index.php at application root is generally accepted as a better practice. There at the entry point you can get

```
$rootPath = str_replace('\\','/',dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
```

and use it all through your application for file access and includes. As a bonus, you can move your entire application without breaking its file relations.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can see why it would be useful for the current script to "know" where it's located. However, I prefer to only do `require __DIR__ . '/../includes/config.php'` for example (just hard-code the site's general include. Aslo, I would still have my complication of a `.htaccess` file that depends on redirects to internal URIs that assume we're working at a top-level URL.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I Hope you find a good solution. Maybe at each entry root accessed via uri's you can put a script showing "the right way" and include as "/whereAmI.php" ? Not looking elegant I know, and maybe your application has too many entry points.

Comment: How about setting an environment variable on the server and reading the directory position from there?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I believe setting an environment variable is the preferred method over using configuration files. Even then, I would still have the `.htaccess` problem, since it doesn't know "where" it's located without hard-coding `BaseUrl` (or similar variable, I don't remember off the top of my head).